# Problem with Date Range in searches

Tags: search, search-results

There seems to be a bug in doing searches on date ranges - specifically in Advanced Search and in Find Contributions. We're using Drupal and Civi 4.6.2.

When I type into Adv Search's Member Since date range fields OR Find Contribution's contribution date range fields only 2 digits for the year (1/1/14) I get a nonsensical number of records back. No error msg, just an obviously wrong set of data. I confirm by looking at several records but they do not match the date range in either Member Since or Contrib Date.

However, when I type in all four year digits, then I get the expected results.

I have tested this in the demo Civi and received the same results for both - only 2 digits gets bad results, 4 digits gets correct one.

I used to be able to type in only 2 digits (since we started using Civi in 11/12).

Please add in an error message or change the field instructions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for taking the time describing the problem.

As it seems to be a bug rather than a question, i think you should create a new issue in the [issue tracker](https://issues.civicrm.org) rather than using Stack Exchange.